# i make sql like this but second select not count rows correctly, and rows duplicated

Tags: sql, postgresql-10

```
select * from (
select distinct nationality,gender,regplacetype,count(gender) as total from population
    where date_part('year',age(to_date(dateofbirth,'DDMMYYYY'))) BETWEEN  16 and 67 and gender = 'Man'
    group by nationality,gender,regplacetype
    ) as man,
(
select distinct nationality,gender,regplacetype,count(nationality) as total from population
    where date_part('year',age(to_date(dateofbirth,'DDMMYYYY'))) BETWEEN  16 and 57 and gender = 'female'
    group by xnationality,gender,regplacetype) as female
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with man as (
select distinct nationality,gender,regplacetype,count(gender) as total from population
    where date_part('year',age(to_date(dateofbirth,'DDMMYYYY'))) BETWEEN  16 and 67 and gender = 'Man'
    group by nationality,gender,regplacetype
    ) select * from man,
union
select distinct nationality,gender,regplacetype,count(nationality) as total from population
    where date_part('year',age(to_date(dateofbirth,'DDMMYYYY'))) BETWEEN  16 and 57 and gender = 'female'
    group by xnationality,gender,regplacetype
```

Comment: thanks its work , but all data in same columns,how make individual columns for male and for female

Comment: use join@ЖигарНамберВан